# When I move a repo on GitHub, how can I forward the old location?

Tags: github

I moved my repo from a personal account to an organization, as more people are getting involved in the project. But if people have the old URL, I want them to be able to find the new location easily. How can I make that happen?

I know that GitHub doesn't support forwarding. I thought of creating a trivial repo at the old name, with a `README.md` pointing to the new location, but I wonder if that will create trouble for anyone who forked the old location?

Answer (score 0):

If the SHA1 are unchanged in your moved repo, they can simply fork again, and see if they can go on pushing their commit from their existing local clone to their new fork (by simply deleting their old fork and forking again: if the name is unchanged, they wouldn't even have to change the remote url for their fork with a `git remote set-url`)

But if the SHA1 differs, then the people who forked the old location is will have to report their local commits onto a new local repo, which will be the clone of a new fork from the new organization repo.